# urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Tags: python, urllib2, recaptcha

I'm writing a script, and it requires to get a reCAPTCHA challenge with a specified public key, so I though if I opened this with `urllib2`:

```
chp = urllib.urlencode(dict({'k': key}))
chg = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge', chp).read()
```

I could then get the challenge from there and return it, but when it does this I get the error:

`urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 405: HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a GET request instead:

```
chp = urllib.urlencode(dict({'k': key}))
chg = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?' + chp).read()
```

As the [`urllib2` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) states:

> data may be a string specifying additional data to send to the server, or None if no such data is needed. Currently HTTP requests are the only ones that use data; the HTTP request will be a POST instead of a GET when the data parameter is provided.

You were passing in `chp` as POST data by passing it to the `urlopen` method as the second positional argument. Concatenating it to the URL with a `?` instead makes it a GET request.

Comment: When printing that, all I get is the parameter of the URL: `k=thekey`

Comment: When printing what? The return value from Google? Doesn't that mean that Google gave you a response and things worked?

Comment: When printing `chg`, all it prints is the parameter I gave it (`k`), an equals sign and the public key (`key`), not the response from Google.

Comment: Try giving your variables better names; `params` and `response` for example, I think you have something mixed up.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I accidentally printed chp instead of chg. I was a bit in a hurry so I never gave them better names. Thanks for the answer!